# Jquery chekbox select all except disabled

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have this jsp code as a header to toggle all checkbox:

```
<th><input name="checkAll" type="checkbox" onClick="toggleCheck(this, this.form.poFulfill);"/></th>
```

Each row reads the record whether that checkbox will be disabled or not:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="poFulfill" value='<%=row.poId.toString()%>'
<%=(row.qtyIn.compareTo(row.qtyOut) == 0))?"disabled":""%>>
```

I want to select all checkbox that is ENABLED only.  I read I need to use jquery so I modified my header to:

```
<th><input id="chkSelectAll" name="checkAll" type="checkbox"/></th>
```

And added this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#chkSelectAll').click(function () {
var checked_status = this.checked;
$('div#item input[type=checkbox]').not(":disabled").prop("checked", checked_status);
});
</script>
```

Not working and nothing happens when I click checkbox to select all.  Any idea?

Comment: Where is `div#item`?

Comment: The logic for checking checkboxes in your jQuery code appears to be intact, I've tested that. However, are the inputs wrapped in a `<div>` element with the ID of `item`? Are you sure that this ID is unique throughout the document?

Comment: Both jsp line is inside <div class="autoscroll">
<table class="reference">
 <thead>

Comment: @ArnoldCristobal, please add more code, if you have multiple elements please add them. Make a minimal example. The code you provided is not enough to replicate the problem you have.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you to use `change()` instead of `click()` when using `checkboxes`, `radios`. I've added a div with `item` id and it seems to work:

```js
$('#chkSelectAll').change(function() {
  var checked_status = this.checked;
  $('div#item input[type=checkbox]').not(":disabled").prop("checked", checked_status);
  console.log($('#chkSelectAll1').is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<th><input id="chkSelectAll" name="checkAll" type="checkbox" /></th>
<div id='item'>
<input id="chkSelectAll1" name="checkAll1" type="checkbox" disabled/>
<input id="chkSelectAll2" name="checkAll2" type="checkbox" />
<input id="chkSelectAll3" name="checkAll3" type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#chkSelectAll').click(function () {
var checked_status = this.checked;
$('div#item input[type=checkbox]:enabled').prop("checked", checked_status);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<th><input id="chkSelectAll" name="checkAll" type="checkbox"/>check all</th>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id='item'>
<th><input id="chk1" name="chk1" type="checkbox" disabled/>abc</th><br/>
<th><input id="chk2" name="chk2" type="checkbox"/>a</th><br/>
<th><input id="chk4" name="chk4" type="checkbox"/>b</th><br/>
<th><input id="chk5" name="chk5" type="checkbox" disabled/>c</th><br/>
<th><input id="chk6" name="chk6" type="checkbox"/>d</th>
</div>
```